# Ubuntu 12.10 desktop/interface not showing on VirtualBox VM after login screen

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox

I'm having some trouble with getting my Ubuntu to work on a VirtualBox VM.
I made a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on a VM without any errors. I arrive at the login screen, as soon as I press enter it does it's little loading thingy and then screen goes black, then this is all I get:

[image]

I can access the terminal and pretty much all the other features through it, but I would like to have the GUI properly working. I've been looking around the web and looking at various fixes to similar problems, but can't seem to get it to work. I'm thinking this problem might have to do with the graphics?

I'm running Windows 8 Pro as host, if that helps, might be some compatibility issues with VirtualBox in W8...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Did you install the [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)?

Comment: I tried that, but made no difference, can try it again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Accepted Answer**

You could alternatively install gnome classic in order to get a functional desktop:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

Reboot the pc and select "Gnome Classic (No Effects)" from the session list.

---

**Original Answer**

> open a terminal and type
>
> `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
>
> after installing type: `ccsm`
>
> hopefully a window will open. tick "Unity".

Comment: Under which category? The closest I can find is the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin", but is already activated, and is under the "Desktop" category...

Comment: When I said open a terminal, I meant press Ctrl+Alt+T. Then type the two commands above....

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I had done that. When i open ccsm, there is no option called just "Unity" :/

Comment: Weird... last time I checked it had for me.. anyway, you could type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity` and/or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I really appreciate the help! Will get back to you once I've done what you've told me!

Comment: Ran both commands and did a reboot, still no luck :/ any more suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you could alternatively install gnome classic in order to get a functional desktop: `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`. Reboot the pc and select "Gnome Classic (No Effects)" from the session list.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for sticking with me! This is truly appreciated!

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Comment: Downvote: The accepted answer doesn't reflect the final solution. Please update the answer and I'll glad change the vote to a positive.

Comment: Changed the main answer. Thanks @JavierRivera for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

I wrestled with this one for a couple of days before a friend told me that I needed to enable Virtualization on my CPU in my BIOS.  That fixed it!