# Looked around A LOT but can't avoid black screen after logging into Ubuntu VM from Mac 10.6 host

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, mac

I've looked at many for ideas and suggestions (here are a few)

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

[Ubuntu 12.10 desktop/interface not showing on VirtualBox VM after login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230304/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-interface-not-showing-on-virtualbox-vm-after-login-screen)

[How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)

[Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-extra-drivers-via-the-command-prompt)

I know these are of disparate topics - but I finally did succeed in installing the guest additions. To start, I have a triple boot and use the mac host mostly, so I put VirtualBox to access the Ubuntu partition. Worked in the past but upgraded to 13.10. Actually I can log in but after that I get a black screen. I've uninstalled Cinnamon and have tried editing the boot with the nomodeset to see if I can get a graphical interace to check the drivers. Even tried jockey-text. BUT, if I boot into the partition from rEFIt, then everything is fine. So I'm a little lost - any ideas?

P.S. By the way, even with the black screen I can go to a virtual terminal and log in and do stuff, but I need a desktop environment for work (working on GUI programming ;)

P.P.S. Also, after trying startx, I also get a system that hangs at "Loading extension GLX" in a virtual terminal - this was mentioned in another post that I cannot find right now....

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we choose a real partition from a multi-boot setup for Virtual Box to boot from we need to make sure there were no conflicting kernel modules installed.

If we are unable to boot the graphical desktop there may be graphics driver modules which do not fit to the virtual box environment, or guest additions modules breaking other modules needed for the bare metal installation.

To overcome this we should set up a small VDI to boot a separate Ubuntu in Virtual Box. We then will be able to share the bare metal HOME (or other directories if needed) for data and settings after adding their corresponding partitions to the virtual machine.

Comment: Hmmm... okay. Like I said, it did work fine with several other Ubuntu versions and the last two VirtualBox programs.... Could you please provide some more input to this? Are you talking about altering the files created by rawdiskcreate?

Answer (score 0):

I increased my video memory for the virtual machine. The default video memory in VirtualBox is 16MB. I set it to 32MB and then it works. If that doesn't work, try 128MB.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1089073/961896